# How to make some file donot be needed to be checked in on TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, source-control-bindings

I have two questions,

1. When you create an Asp.NET web project (mvc or web forms), Next to the project folder another folder (Packages) for dependent assemblies is created. Do I need to check in these files?
2. If you don't want to check in some kind of files, What do you need to do to these files that they do not be showen in pending changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .tfignore file to tell TFS/VS to ignore certain files/folders.  See more info here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)